# Include a collection and then a collection one level down

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to query a collection and child collection using EF 7. Here's the code:

```
public async Task < List < Table >> GetAllTable() {
  var tableList = await db.Tables.Include(o => o.Checks.Select(i => i.CheckItems)).ToListAsync();
  return tableList;

}
```

I'm following the syntax from here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx). However, when i run this code i'm getting the following error. Does anyone know what went wrong here? Thanks!

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Remotion.Linq.Clauses.Expressions.SubQueryExpression' to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.**
>   Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.b__30_2(<>f__AnonymousType2`2
>   <>h__TransparentIdentifier0)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation you are reading is for EF 5.

The [design meeting notes](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Design-Meeting-Notes:-January-8,-2015) for EF 7 say the syntax of this has changed - try this:

```
db.Tables.Include(t => t.Checks)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.CheckItems)
    .ToListAsync()
```

Comment: Solved mine as well!