# ef7 unable to retrieve child collections' child object's properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

[EF7 doesn't support lazy loading of child objects](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3312), but does support the `.Include()` function.  That being said, I'm struggling with something and am not sure if it just isn't possible in EF7, or I've just been staring at this too long.

Suppose something like the following (checking `reg.Activities.Task.Ordinal` (an `int`), Task is always null, even when I check the DB myself and am certain there is in fact a related record)...

```
public void SomeOtherMethod()
    var r = getRegistration(User.UserName);
    var act = r.Activities
      .Where(a => a.IsDone == false)  // unfinished
      .OrderByDescending(o => o.Task.Ordinal)  // Task indicates activity type, is always null
      .FirstOrDefault();  // to get a user's most recent unfinished activity

    //DO SOMETHING WITH ACT
}

public Registration getRegistration(string userName) {
    var reg = _context.Registrations
      .Where(r => r.User.UserName == userName)  // this works however?
      .Include(r => r.Acvitities)  // List<Activity>
      .FirstOrDefault();

      return reg;
}
```

...I have the [navigation properties](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#conventions) in place in the model classes, but `.Task` above is null and not loaded.

Further, since the query has been projected, I can't `.Include` additional properties any more in the creation of `act`.  I cant `.ThenInclude` in the creation of `reg` because class `Registration` does not include a definition for a `Task` property (but `Registration` does have a collection of `Activities` that are `List<Activity>`, and `Activity` does have a `Task` that is related to another table/class that defines the tasks and the order they should be presented to users per `Activity`.

I've tried various incantations of `.Join`, `.Include` and `.ThenInclude` hoping to be able to join the `Task` to each of the `Activities` while returning the `Registration` object, but this fails because `Registration` itself does not contain a `Task` property.

I considered creating a new issue on GitHub, but am not yet certain that it isn't very doable and I'm just not looking at this correctly.

**UPDATE1:** Mihail suggested using... 
`.Include(r => r.Activities.Select(resp => resp.Responses))` 
...but this yields an exception.  This SO (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30151601/3246805) indicates thats for EF5 and that `.ThenInclude` should be used.

However, trying that suggestion... 
`.ThenInclude(r => r.Select(t => t.Task))` 
...yields the following Exception...

```
The properties expression 'r => {from Activity t in r select [t].Task}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.
Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression
```

**UPDATE2:** Stafford asked for schema. Best effort at a sharable repo...

```
public class RegistrationData {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public MyUser User { get; set; }    // MyUser : IdentityUser

    //blah blah, more fields

    public List<UserTask> Activitys { get; set; }
}

public class UserTask {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsDone { get; set; } = false;

    [Required]
    public int RegistrationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public RegistrationData Registration { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Task Task { get; set; }

    public List<UserResponse> Responses { get; set; }
}

public class Task {
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] // ID comes from loaded config
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Ordinal { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}

public class UserResponse {
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int UserTaskId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int QuestionNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You should have an other line like this: .Include(r => r.Acvitities.Select(t=>t.Task)), after the include of the Activities

Comment: @MihailStancescu Man that looked beautiful and I hoped that would solve it, but it is throwing an exception in getRegistration when creating `reg` variable... `Unable to cast object of type 'Remotion.Linq.Clauses.Expressions.SubQueryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `Include` followed by `ThenInclude` for the child's child properties.  The child properties may not show up in intellisense for `ThenInclude`, but just enter it anyway - it will compile and operate as expected.

```
var reg = _context.Registrations
  .Where(r => r.User.UserName == userName)
  .Include(r => r.Acvitities).ThenInclude(a => a.Task)
  .Include(r => r.Activities).ThenInclude(a => a.SomethingElse)
  .FirstOrDefault();
  return reg;
```

Comment: This is so close to what I need! It does in fact solve the problem of the Task property!  I tried using the same concept to then gather an additional property off the same object that is a `List` of objects.  With no luck.  Ideas?  Can there be multiple `.ThenInclude`s?  Seems like it should be doable, I'm just not getting it quite right.  The second chains off the previous (the Task class).  Another `.Include(r => r.Acvitities)` doesn't quite seem right either.

Comment: @t.j. There can be multiple `.Include(something).ThenInclude(something)`.  Show your schema and what property/ies you're trying to include.

Comment: This suggests it's doable...  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2274

Comment: The `a.SomethingElse` in your updated suggestion is the `List<UserResponse> Responses` in the schema now provided above. When I hit the dot and then "something else" (`Responses`), I only get the list of `IEnumberable` functions/methods (eg: `Count`, `Capacity`, `Select`, `Where`, etc)

Comment: These too suggest that your example **should** work... https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4058#issuecomment-164850977 https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2274

Comment: Are you implying it doesn't?

Comment: @t.j. Oh, I saw your previous comment.  Don't worry about the intellisense.  Just write it and it will compile :)

Comment: **It does**, how/why?  Is the intellisense a bug that MS is aware of? How did you know it would work even though VS couldn't figure it out? :)  Nice Bubble Bobble reference in your avatar btw

Comment: Not sure why intellisense doesn't work, you could [open an issue](github.com/aspnet/entityframework/issues/new).  I had seen the syntax before, so when intellisense didn't work, I just tried completing the statement anyway and saw that it compiled.  After writing the statement, then highlighting the `.` and pressing `.` again, intellisense seems to work.  May be because of how `ThenInclude` depends on the previous parts of the query.

Comment: Hey @StaffordWilliams. Would you mind adding a bit of text instead of just a single block of code? Just so that we don't need to browse the comments and find the relevant bits?